# Android save Integer HashSet

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, hashset

I want to save Integer ArrayList to sharedpreferrence with HashSet, but I can only do this with String ArrayList. I have tried converting each of the integers to strings but then I  have to change a lot of code. Maybe there is an easier way?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba4XB.png

Comment: Please don't add your code as image, but as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for lists of items in `SharedPreferences` (except for `String`). The easiest way to do this is to write yourself a convenience method that converts an array of integers into a `String` and vice versa. Then store the `String` in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: What if I would use ObjectSerializer to save it?

Comment: If you'de rather use something else than write your own code, sure. It's kinda overkill, but will work. You just need something that can convert a list of integers into a `String` and vice versa. There are probably also libraries or code snippets that provide extended support for arrays and things in `SharedPreferences`, if you want to go hunting for one.